# What is route leaking?

Tags: routing, route, redistribution

I tried googling, but didn't find a good article explaining this.

What roughly i understand it, advertising route from one vrf table to other.
What type of routes (static, connected, dynamic routes) can be leaked from one vrf to another ?
And why do we need route leaking?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> What roughly I understand is, advertising route from one vrf table to other.

In the context of MPLS, yes. Or, leaking from the global table into one or more VRFs.  It is also used in other places, *e.g.,* IS-IS.

> What type of routes (static, connected, dynamic routes) can be leaked from one vrf to another ?

Anything in the routing table.

> And why do we need route leaking?

A common example is leaking a default route from the global table into several VRFs, so each one gets a default route to the Internet.  There are several examples of this that you can read about on the web.